# Solicito colaboración - Tengo la solución parcial de un algoritmo en Python

Tags: python, bucle-for, algoritmos

no soy experto en programación y tengo parcialmente la solución de un ejercicio en el cual debo ingresar tres valores, los dos primeros son cadenas de bits recibidas en los parámetros bits1 y bits2, el tercero, es una cadena de texto que contiene el nombre de la operación ("AND","OR","XOR") a realizar entre la cadena bits1 y bits2. El ejercicio básicamente consiste en comparar las dos cadenas de bits y dependiendo de los números que se encuentren en la misma posición y según el tipo de operación elegida, el arrojara una cadena de bits como resultado de haber evaluado las siguientes condiciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he ejecutado los condicionales dentro del ciclo for de manera independiente sin incluirlos dentro de la función y funciona perfecto ya que dependiendo de la condición que se aprecia en la imagen adjunta, cambia el valor de 0 y 1, pero cuando lo incluyo dentro de la función y al querer retornar el resultado, siento que estoy olvidando algo o cometiendo un error. En razón a lo anterior, me gustaría me guiaran para poder encontrar yo mismo la solución al ejercicio. Gracias

```
def calculadora(bits1, bits2, OP):
    
    for i,j in zip(bits1,bits2):
        resultado = ""
        if OP == "OR" and (i == "0" and j == "0"):
            resultado = "0"
        else:
            resultado = "1"
        if OP == "AND" and (i == "1" and j == "1"):
            resultado = "1"     
        else:
            resultado = "0"
        if OP == "XOR" and (i == j):
            resultado = "0"
        else:
            resultado = "1"
    
    return resultado
    
calculadora("0110110110","1100011101","OR") #Resultado esperado: 1110111111
calculadora("0110110110","1100011101","AND") #Resultado esperado: 0100010100
calculadora("0110110110","1100011101","XOR") #Resultado esperado: 101010101
```

Comment: necesitas hacer las operaciones tu mismo o te puedes ayudar de *los operadores bitwise*?

Comment: Yo mismo tengo que hacerlas.

Comment: tranquilo ya estoy escribiendo una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código solo devolverá el ultimo digito por 2 razones.

1. En cada iteración `resultado` vuelve a ser vacío `""`
2. Estas reemplazando el valor de `resultado`

Para solucionar tu error se puede mover la variable resultado arriba del ciclo `for`, luego tendrías que colocar `+=` en cada asignación de `resultado`, esto es para ir concatenando los resultados. Te mostrare una forma mas sencilla y simplificada de hacer tu ejercicio.

Para realizar la operación podríamos ayudarnos de una función `lambda`, la cual nos permite realizar operaciones sencillas y concretas. La sintaxis de una *lambda* es la siguiente:

```py
lambda parametros: expresion
```

Esto es *casi* lo mismo que una función, solo que las *lambdas* son anónimas. podemos hacer esto:

```py
suma = lambda x,y: x+y

print(suma(1,3))
#resultado-> 4
```

Así que vamos a usarlas, primero declaramos las funciones y ponemos las condiciones. Las *lambdas* ya retornan un valor por lo que podemos usar los **operadores ternario** `0 if x==1 else 1`, esto quiere decir que se retorna el valor de 0 si x es igual a 1 de lo contrario se retorna 1.

```py
def calculadora(bits1, bits2, OP):
    
    resultado = ""
    #declaramos las funciones
    op_or = lambda p,q: "0" if (p,q) == ("0","0") else "1"
    op_and = lambda p,q: "1" if (p,q) == ("1","1") else "0"
    op_xor = lambda p,q: "1" if p !=q and (int(p) or int(q)) else "0" 

    for i,j in zip(bits1,bits2):
       #con .lower() convertimos a minusculas
        if OP.lower() == "or":
            resultado += op_or(i,j) #hacemos la operacion
        elif OP.lower() == "and":
            resultado += op_and(i,j)
        elif OP.lower() == "xor":
            resultado += op_xor(i,j)

    return resultado
```

Esta es una muy buena alternativa pero...... no tiene sentido, mas sentido tuviese si en vez de pasar un valor por cada iteración le pasemos toda la cadena de bits, y en ese caso el código se reduce aun mas, yo no lo haré pero puedes investigar sobre funciones como `reduce`, `map` y `filter`.

Ahora vamos a ver una alternativa mejor, antes mencionamos los *operadores ternario* (`0 if x==1 else 1`), esto es lo único que necesitamos para resolver el ejercicio, pues se nos dará un valor en caso se cumpla una condición de lo contrario nos da el otro valor. Es lo mismo que tu haces `if/else` pero mas simplificado

```py
def calculadora(bits1, bits2, OP):
    
    resultado = ""

    for i,j in zip(bits1,bits2):
        if OP.lower() == "or":
            resultado += "0" if (i,j) == ("0","0") else "1"
        elif OP.lower() == "and":
            resultado += "1" if (i,j) == ("1","1") else "0"
        elif OP.lower() == "xor":
            resultado += "1" if i !=j and (int(i) or int(j)) else "0"

    return resultado
```

**probamos**

```
res = calculadora("0110110110","1100011101","OR") #Resultado esperado: 1110111111
print(res)
#comprobamos con la salida esperada
print(res == "1110111111") 
print()

res = calculadora("0110110110","1100011101","AND") #Resultado esperado: 0100010100
print(res)
#comprobamos con la salida esperada
print(res == "0100010100")
print()

res = calculadora("0110110110","1100011101","XOR") #Resultado esperado: 101010101
print(res)
#comprobamos con la salida esperada
print(res == "101010101")
```

**resultado**

```
1110111111
True

0100010100
True

1010101011
False
```

No te asustes, el resultado del ultimo caso es correcto, creo que tu salida esperada esta mal, pues si analizamos el penúltimo carácter de ambos bits (bit1=`1`,bit2=`0`) y aplicamos la operación *XOR* el resultado es `1` así que esta bien.

**Nota:** El mismo resultado es para la primera opción.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo amigo. Agradezco tu excelente explicación y tiempo para ayudarme con el ejercicio, solo le ajuste un par de cosas y lo probé, funciono perfectamente. También me llamo la atención lo de los operadores ternarios y como estos simplifican una operación, no lo sabia y lo tendré muy en cuenta. Solo me queda agradecerte y si no es mucha molestia me gustaría saber de que manera identificaste el error y llegaste a la solución, tienes algunos consejos?

Comment: Trata de pensar que es lo que ocurre en cada proceso, desglosa el problema por partes, si vez que el resultado es solo un dígito y debería ser varios es porque algo no está bien, ve y busca la parte referente a eso, si te resulta complicado un `print()` ayuda mucho.

Comment: El consejo que te puedo dar es que hagas más programas y piensa *¿como puedo simplificar esto?*. Aquí, en StackOverflow, hay muchas preguntas y respuestas muy útiles, lee algunas y verás como descubres nuevas cosas

Comment: Gracias. Si, justamente pasaba que me devolvía un solo valor o digito al ejecutar el código, que la variable resultado la cual es el contador la estaba declarando dentro del for y no por fuera como debe ser, al igual, esa misma variable debía aplicarle la lógica de resultado += (resto del codigo). Un abrazo amigo, gracias por tu consejo.